# What was gpowershell.exe? Does it still exist?

Tags: powershell

I came across [blog posts talking about gpowershell.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mediaandmicrocode/microcode-all-about-modules-windows-powershell-ctp2) (in Powershell 2.0 CTP) however, I didn't find any more recent information on what this tool is, whether it's included in later versions of powershell and so on, where it's been renamed. What's the real story here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GPowershell was in the version 2 CTP and became the Powershell ISE in release.